# Free pointer after affectation to another one

Tags: c, linux

I have the following source code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int *ptr1,*ptr2;       // two pointers of type int

  ptr2=ptr1;
  ptr1=NULL;

  if(ptr2==NULL)
     printf("OK Clean\n");
   else
     printf("KO not clean\n");

}
```

I would like to know why the pointer `ptr2` is not `NULL`, I get always `KO not clean`?
If I affect `ptr1` to `ptr2` and make `ptr1` `NULL` , `ptr2` in this case must be `NULL`?
How can do to get a `NULL` in `ptr2`?

Comment: Easy. `ptr2 = NULL`. Or change the order of assignments. C isn't declarative.

Answer (score 1):

This is *undefined behaviour*: you're assigning `ptr2` to an uninitialised value `ptr1`.

Writing `ptr1 = ptr2 = NULL;` would be safe. `NULL` is the only literal value that you can assign to a pointer, without using the address-of operator `&`. (As a further remark, you shouldn't *assume* that `NULL` is related to memory address 0: the standard doesn't).

Comment: They're actually assigning uninitialized `ptr1` to `ptr2`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Bathsheba refers, this has `undefined behaviour` problem. But I think @Issam want to know why the `ptr2` is  not changed.
For the code belowing:

```
    int *ptr1,*ptr2;       // two pointers of type int
    int num = 2;
    ptr2=ptr1 = #
    ptr1 = NULL;
    if(ptr2==NULL)
        printf("OK Clean\n");
    else
        printf("KO not clean\n");
```

The result is still `KO`.
The `point equal` means the 2 points has the same memory address, and when `ptr1` points to  `NULL`, it will not have effect on `ptr2`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in here.

- Using `ptr2 = ptr1` is invalid.
- Why does assignment to `ptr1` not change `ptr2`?

**Invalid assignment**

`ptr1` uninitialized and value is garbage. Assigment to `ptr2` leads to undefined behaviour. The program is broken.

To fix this, initialize `ptr1` with valid address:

```
int a = 2;
int * ptr1 = &a; // Initialize ptr1
int * ptr2;
ptr2 = ptr1; // Assigment OK, ptr1 has valid address
```

**Assigment to `ptr1` not changing `ptr2`**

`ptr1` and `ptr2` hold same value, but have no connection to each other. It's same as

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
a = b; // a is now 2
b = 0; // a is still 2
```

If changing value of `ptr1` should reflect on `ptr2`, it should be pointer to pointer:

```
int * ptr1 = &a;  
int ** ptr2;
ptr2 = &ptr1;
ptr1 = NULL;
if(*ptr2 == NULL) // Test value of ptr1 through ptr2
```

Comment: I would like to say thanks you to all stackoverflow member for here reponses, thank you t think that the response posted by @user694733 is the good one we should use the adresse of pointer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning the address of ptr1 to pointer ptr2. SO this is the reason that is not null.

```
ptr2=ptr1;
```

You want to make the pointer as null. You can assign like this.

```
ptr2=ptr1=NULL; or
ptr2=NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignement `ptr2 = ptr1` only says that *at that time* ptr2 and ptr1 point to same memory. But as you later modify the pointer `ptr1` they are different again.

It would be different in you were changing the *pointed value* :

```
int i = 5;
int * ptr1, *ptr2;
ptr1 = ptr2 = &i;
*ptr2 = 3;
```

Then `*ptr1` also has value 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the value of a pointer (the address it stores) with the value **it points to**. When the two pointers `ptr1` and `ptr2` point to the same address, then changing the value that address points to will affect both pointers. But the addresses both pointers store store (the addresses they point to) can still be **different**! So be careful to distinguish the value of a pointer (it's address) and the value **it points to**.